# What to call a variable that is used for indentation?

Tags: c#

What should I call a variable that is used for indentation?

```
private string _indentString = "\t"; // can be set to "   " or "\t\t", etc.
```

Is the purpose of the variable clear from the name?

Comment: `_amountOfIndent`?

Comment: Is this a silly question? Is that why I'm being downvoted?

Comment: Unfortunately an answer to this question is primarily opinion-based. There are no silly question. No downvote from me but a close vote.

Comment: More context please. We can't even see why the variable is needed, much less suggest a name for it or review the "code".

Comment: @200_success There are several places in code where we prepend the output with `"     "`. I wanted a variable to store that information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it's fine.  As long as it's descriptive to someone coming after you to follow.  I usually try to follow a .NET class if I know they have something similar.  In this case I would have followed the `xmlwriter` class [IndentChars](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwritersettings.indentchars(v=vs.110).aspx) property.  But it's quibbling over little things and not worth investing too much time once you have a name that is clear.